# How do I make edges tube-shaped?

Tags: modeling

I have a large block. I want the edges of this block to have a cylindrical mesh centered around them, spanning the entire length of the edge. I want to be able to choose the circumference of the cylinder. I want it to follow the edges like with the curves in the first 5 minutes of [this video](https://youtu.be/Nn7mISvVzJk). If this is possible, how do I do it? If possible, link a video because i am not very good with technical terms.

Comment: Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

Comment: i doubt if the video is really necessary to understand my issue but the problem is i don't have any image of what i want.

Comment: the step by step seems to be what i want but right now it is way too thicc, it looks more like a pancake then what you showed, how to i thinn it out?

Comment: never mind ctrl a worked

Answer (score 0):

I think this method may work:

Step 1: Press delete and select "Only faces"

[image]

Step 2: Add a skin modifier

[image]

Make sure to select "Smooth shading"

[image]

Step 3: add a subdivision modifier

[image]

Step 4: enter edit mode with "X-Ray" enabled

[image]

Step 5: Press CTRL + A to adjust the radius

[image]

**Step 6, and all the ones after are optional, but they can give your object a more defined shape.**

Step 6: Subdivide your edges in edit mode

[image]

Step 7: Select only the newly created vertices

[image]

Finally, press CTRL + SHIFT + B to bevel the vertices. Adjust untill you get a result you like

[image]